# Return characters between each set of delimiters in a string

Tags: ruby, parsing, functional-programming

I have a string that looks like this:

```
"[hello][my][friend]"
```

I'm interested in returning an array like

`["hello", "my", "friend"]`

How can I do this in Ruby?

Comment: Why is the question tagged _functional-programming_?

Comment: Can you tell us how you got that string? This sounds like it is an XY Problem. See "[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/153968)"
for more information. Also, see the "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many ways.

```
str = "[hello][my][friend]"
```

Here are a few that use [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-scan). All return `["hello", "my", "friend"]`:

Match one or more characters other than `'['` and `']'`:

```
str.scan /[^\[\]]+/
```

Match one or more Unicode alphanumeric characters:

```
str.scan /\p{Alnum}+/
```

Match one or more characters, lazily, in a capture group, bracketed by `'['` and `']'`:

```
str.scan(/\[(.+?)\]/).flatten
```

Match any number of any character `(.+)`, lazily `(?)`, immediately preceded by `'['` (`(?<=\[)` being a *positive lookbehind*) and immediately followed by `']'` (`(?=\])` being a *positive lookahead*):

```
str.scan /(?<=\[).+?(?=\])/
```

If `.+` is not made lazy (i.e., is greedy), there will be just one match: `"hello][my][friend"`, which of course is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
str.split(%r{\[(.*?)\]}).reject(&:empty?)
=> ["hello", "my", "friend"]
```

Comment: Whenever `split` gives you an unwanted string at the beginning and/or end of the array try using `scan`.

Comment: Please add a small explanation why this post answers the question.